# Describe discrete-time Langevin dynamics by its stationary distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, markov-chains, nonlinear-dynamics

Let's consider stochastic dynamics with discrete time step $t$ and states $x_t\in\mathbb{R}^d$ that evolve as

$$
\mathrm{p}(x_{t+1}|x_t)=\mathcal{N}(x_t+f(x_t), \Sigma).
$$

Moreover, we assume the existence of a unique stationary distribution $\rho(x)$ that satisfies

$$
\int\mathrm{p}(x_t|x_{t-1})\rho(x_{t-1})\mathrm{d}x_{t-1}=\rho(x_t).
$$

Can $f$ be written as a gradient descent on $\ln\rho$ transformed by a positive semi-definite matrix $R(x)$,

$$
\mathrm{p}(x_{t+1}|x_t)=\mathcal{N}(x_t+R(x_t)\nabla_{x_t}\ln\rho(x_t),\Sigma)\,?
$$

Do I additionally need to assume ergodicity or detailed balance for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Counterexample:

State space = $\{0,1,2\}$

$p_1: x_{t+1}=x_t+1 $ mod $ 3$

$p_2: x_{t+1}=x_t-1 $ mod $ 3$

so $\Sigma=0$.

Then the same $\rho(x_t)$ belongs to both $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean the deterministic systems $p_1(x_{t+1}|x_t)=\delta(x_{t+1}=x_t+1 \,\text{mod}\, 3)$ and $p_1(x_{t+1}|x_t)=\delta(x_{t+1}=x_t-1 \,\text{mod}\, 3)$? I think these systems have no stationary distribution $\rho(x)$. Also, technically $x_t\in\mathbb{R}^d$, but an example with discrete states could already be helpful.

Comment: They do have a stationary distribution, it's uniform. It isn't ergodic, but even with ergodicity you cannot do this. The canonical way to do it is called reversible dynamics.

Comment: @danijar thanks, that's right. I agree with Ian that the stationary distribution is uniform. We can generalize this example to continuous $x_t$ by making $f_{1},f_2$ that go clockwise resp. counter clockwise around the same point. They'll have the same stationary distribution.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense that the stationary distribution is uniform, although it is not ergodic. @Ian, would you mind explaining how this can be done with reversible dynamics? What I had in mind was a discrete-time version of the equilibrium solution to Fokker-Planck in ergodic SDEs with Gaussians noise.